# Index was outside the bounds of the array error. C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create a two dimensional numeric array in c#. In which there are the following simple methods: generates the array, shows the array results in the console and finally counts and shows the sum of all of the rows and columns in it.

But when i am trying to get the sums of rows and columns i get this error:

[image]

The number of rows and columns are specified in the first row of the data.txt file.(5 rows and 7 columns)

The data.txt file looks like this:

[image]

This is my first post in SOF so i apologize for any mistakes.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what does `i` equal in comparison to the array's upper bound?

Comment: Please don't post code as pictures.

Comment: Please embed your code in your question.  The only way that I think you could run into this problem is that you have more columns than rows.

Comment: switch the loop-variables (first rows, then columns)

Comment: Check your for loop and array initialization. Once you use the number of columns, once the number of rows.

Comment: You are dimensioning the result array according to the number of rows, but then your i variables counts the columns. If columns > rows then.....

Comment: maniak1982 you sir were right the error dissapeared as soon as i made the row and column number equal. Sorry abuot the mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column count `!=` row count - it should be

`result = new int[columns]` instead of `result = new int[rows]`

since you initialize result with `result = new int[rows]` and `i` is iterating the columns

Comment: Up voted this answer. As array is initialized with rows and the loop is iterating on columns so the columns can be greater than row which causes the error.

Comment: I am facepalming myself right now about this error. Thank you kind sir.